# Статьи на русском и украинском языке в одной категории. Как отнесутся ПС?

Tags: seo, поисковые-системы

У меня есть русскоязычный [сайт](http://www.alkonarkostop.com.ua), рассчитанный на аудиторию из Украины. У меня вопрос - если я буду изредка добавлять статьи, разумеется уникальные, на украинском языке. То есть в некоторых разделах будут статьи на русском и украинском языках. Как это повлияет на поисковую оптимизацию? Как отреагируют поисковые системы?

З. Ы. Делать новый раздел  под украинский язык скорее всего нет смысла... так как статей будет не много.

Answer (score 2):

Хватит раскручивать свой алконаркосайт, поисковики будут рассматривать текст, как русский с ошибками или украинский с ошибками.

Comment: @Get думаете Гугл и Яндекс не умеет определять язык статьи?

Comment: @eprivalov1, а Вы сами-то всегда можете отличить русский от украинского?